# #include <fut.h> file not found

Tags: c

I am currently working on a simulation using OpenMP. Whenever I try to execute with --trace to get the trace of the execution I get the following error

```
src/trace_graphics.c:5:10: fatal error: fut.h: No such file or directory
5 | #include <fut.h>
```

I redownloaded easypap but the file doesn't seem to come with it.

Comment: Where is fut.h? Is it in the same folder as src/trace_graphics.c? Also, if fut.h is a header file you created, you're going to want to use '#include "fut.h"

Comment: The file src/trace_graphics.c came with the package easypap and it doesn't contain any fut.h file so to rephrase my question is there any library called fut.h ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I friend of mine found the solution so I'm posting it

```
sudo apt-get install libfxt-dev
```

This will do the trick